# What are "other" requests in Cosmos DB insights when creating items?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My database is configured to auto scale from 500 to 5000RUs/s.
Once a day I'm running an import where about 2.5 million items are created. The parition key is the date in format "2022-02-10". I'm using bulk updates and transactional batches.

I can observe two things:

1. I'm getting status 429 pretty quickly
2. There are many "other" requests showing up in Insights (see below)

[image]

What are the "other" requests I see here? I'm only creating items, nothing else queries the DB. Or could these be the transactional batches not showing up as individual creates?

Answer (score 0):

After some more testing I can confirm that transactional batches end up as "other" in Insights, even if they include only create operations.

This also means it has nothing to do with the 429s.